# Mosaico mail template URL's don't function properly

Tags: mailing, mosaico, urls

I'm using Mosaico to create a mail template. I have 4 different tokens in the email (2 web links and 2 Mailto: addresses).  When the test email comes through everything looks good but the live segments all open the same webpage for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you screen shot the URL's in the template, test and live?

Answer (score 1):

Paul, welcome to CiviCRM stackechange. when you have clickthrough enabled for the mailing CiviCRM replaces those url into trackable url so that Civi can track clicks for mailing. Check you Resource url setting (Administer >> System Settings >> Resource url .. click on '?' under the help area), Make sure [civicrm.path] is set correctly. Try sending the same email by replacing the path for CiviCRM resource url field.